# Strapi V4 GraphQL custom resolver

Tags: graphql, strapi

**Strapi Version**: **4.11.1**

Hello,

I'm trying to make a call in a custom resolver in GraphQL, but the query is not returning the values of the images and nested components.

In my src/index.js I tryed following:

`

```
extensionService.use(({ strapi }) => ({
  typeDefs: `
    type CustomImageType {
      url: String
      width: Int
      height: Int
    }

    type CustomFirstSectionCardType {
      title: String
      description: String
      img: CustomImageType
    }

    type CustomFirstSectionType {
      title: String
      description: String
      img: CustomImageType
      cards: [CustomCardCicloType]
    }

    type CustomSecondSectionType {
      title: String
      description: String
      info: String
    }

    type CustomThirdSectionCardType {
      icon: CustomImageType
      text: String
    }

    type CustomThirdSectionTypes {
      title: String
      description: String
      cardTitle: String
      cards: [CustomCardMentoriaType]
    }

    type CustomHomeType {
      first: CustomFirstSectionType
      second: CustomSecondSectionType
      third: CustomThirdSectionType
    }

    type Query {
      customHome: CustomHomeType
    }
  `,
  resolvers: {
    Query: {
      customHome: {
        resolve: async (parent, args, context) => {
          const data = await strapi.db.query("api::home.home").findOne({ 
            populate: true
          });
          
          console.log(data);
          

          const firstSectionData = data.FirstSection;
          const firstSectionCards = firstSectionData.Cards.map((card) => ({
            title: card.Title,
            description: card.Description,
            img: {
              url: card.CardImage.url,
              width: card.CardImage.width,
              height: card.CardImage.height,
            }
          }));
          const firstSection = {
            title: firstSectionData.Title,
            description: firstSectionData.Description,
            cards: firstSectionCards,
          };

          const secondSectionData = data.SecondSection;
          const secondSection = {
            title: secondSectionData.SectionTitle,
            description: secondSectionData.SectionDescription,
            info: secondSectionData.AdditionalInfo,
          };

          const thirdSectionData = data.ThirdSection;
          const thirdSectionCards = thirdSectionData.ThirdSectionCard.map((card) => ({
            text: card.Text,
            icon: {
              url: card.Icon.url,
              width: card.Icon.width,
              height: card.Icon.height,
            }
          }));
          const thirdSection = {
            title: thirdSectionData.Title,
            description: thirdSectionData.Description,
            cardTitle: thirdSectionData.CardTitle,
            cards: thirdSectionCards,
          }

          return {
            firstSection,
            secondSection,
            thirdSection,
          };
        }
      }
    },
  },
  resolversConfig: {
    "Query.customHome": {
      auth: false,
    },
  },
}));
```

`

I put a console.log, and the data response comes without the images and Card components from the first and third sections.
Like this:
`{ id: 1, createdAt: '2023-06-21T17:01:27.763Z', updatedAt: '2023-06-21T17:04:56.225Z', publishedAt: '2023-06-21T17:04:56.206Z', FirstSection: { id: 1, Title: 'text goes here', Description: 'text goes here' }, SecondSection: { id: 1, SectionTitle: 'text goes here', SectionDescription: 'text goes here', AdditionalInfo: 'text goes here' }, ThirdSection: { id: 1, Title: 'text goes here', Description: 'text goes here', CardTitle: 'text goes here', }, }`

What is the correct way to make the request and receive all the information from the card components and images?